# Cannot connect to KVM virtual machine using VNC (connection hangs)

Tags: vnc, linux-kvm

I have been able to connect to KVM virtual machine since creation using the following commands.

I create a SSH tunnel using `ssh admin@10.0.1.2 -L 5903:127.0.0.1:5903 -N -T` and then run `open vnc://localhost:5903` on macOS.

Problem is VNC connection now hangs indefinitely.

Perhaps it has something to do with me running `virsh undefine vm` by mistake and restoring config using `virsh dumpxml vm > vm.xml && virsh define vm.xml`?

How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! `virsh undefine vm` had cleared password from config.

Had to manually add password by appending `passwd='password goes here' keymap='en-us'` to `<graphics type='vnc'...` using `virsh edit vm`.